# PFQuery whereKey: equalTo: not returning value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have .swift file. I am trying to query Parse data class.

```
var array2: NSArray = self.faveTeams.allKeys
println(array2)
```

returns

```
(
    607371,
    716774,
    427263,
    566108
)
```

Query:

```
findTimelineData.whereKey("awayTeamID", equalTo:array2[0])
```

returns nothing. But

```
findTimelineData.whereKey("awayTeamID", equalTo:607371)
```

returns data. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swift arrays are specific about the type of information they store - it might be that your are storing NSStrings of numbers instead of NSNumbers. I would check to make sure you are sending the correct data type to Parse - if you send an NSString of the number instead of the NSNumber it would explain your null return.